# Expected value of $g(X)$.

Tags: probability, notation

If $\mathrm{E}(X) = \sum_{x\in I} x\,\mathrm{P}(X=x)$, how can I deduce that $E(g(X)) = \sum_{x\in ?} g(x)\,\mathrm{P}(X=x)$? I don't see why it isn't $E(g(X)) = \sum_{g(x)\in ?} g(x)\,\mathrm{P}(X=g(x))$ instead.

Are these simply definitions, or is there any logic behind this notation?

Comment: $X$ is in use here as the notation of a random variable. So do not use as indexset also (as is done in $\sum_{x\in X}$).

Comment: x is the values of X; this is common notation.

Comment: @William I am talking about $\cdots\in X$. There $X$ is a set.

Comment: Oh yeah good point. I agree actually. Sorry my bad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To follow your line of reasoning, we would *actually* have
$$
E\left[g(X)\right]=\sum_{x}g(x)P(g(X)=g(x)).
$$
Assume that $g$ is injective. Then, $g(X)=g(x)$ if and only if $X=x$,
and the above becomes
$$
E\left[g(X)\right]=\sum_{x}g(x)P(X=x).
$$
You can make a similar argument in the case that $g$ is not injective.

Comment: I'm not sure if I should split this and ask in a new question, but why are you allowed to say $g(X)$ and $g(x)$? How can $g$ take different objects?

Comment: g(X) is the function defined as $g\circ X $. Also @par, a similar argument holds if $g$ is not injective, not the same argument.

Comment: Ah, that's right... $f(\cdot)$ is a bit misleading notation...

Comment: @William: +1. I have incorporated your edits in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Generally speaking, we start with the expectations of sums of indicator random variables, which are defined as:

$\Sigma_x x P(\{\omega: X(\omega)=x\})$

as you correctly noted.

Then, for such a simple random variable, if we take $g(X)$, we have:

$P(\{\omega: g(X)(\omega)=y\}=P(\bigcup_{x:g(x)=y} \{\omega: X(\omega)=x\})=\sum_{x:g(x)=y} P(\{\omega: X(\omega)=x\}$

Therefore,

$E[g(X)]=\Sigma_y y P(\{\omega: g(X)(\omega)=y\} =\Sigma_y y(\sum_{x:g(x)=y} P(\{\omega: X(\omega)=x\})$

and then by factoring terms:

$=\Sigma_x g(x) P(\{\omega: X(\omega)=x\})$.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Maybe you can expand the "then by factoring terms"

Answer (score 3):

[image]
I created a small illustration with the expectation (no pun intended) that it might help some learners.

HTH