# $E(X)= \int_{x \in \mathbb{R}}{x \cdot f_X(x) dx}$ implies $Eg(X)= \int_{x \in \mathbb{R}}{g(x) \cdot f_X(x) dx}$ on continuous random variables

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

Let $X$ be a random variable with values in $\mathbb{R}$ and let $g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ a measurable function such that $ E g(X) $ exist.

If we define the expected value as $E(X)= \int_{x \in \mathbb{R}}{x \cdot f_X(x) dx}$, how can I deduce that $E(g(X))= \int_{x \in \mathbb{R}}{g(x) \cdot  f_X(x) dx}$?

I know that this was asked before ( discrete case). Here [Discrete case](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1771231/expected-value-of-gx)

My problem is that I cannot use the same technique here.

Comment: First try indicator functions... and so on. More complexity, till every possible function

Comment: Besides, you define $E(X)$ for continuous $X$, what if $g(X)$ isn't continuous?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A fundamental theorem in measure theory is the key. Let $(\Omega, F, P)$ be a probability space. 
By definition we have $\mathbb{E} g(X) = \int_{\Omega} g(X) dP$. We are aware that $g(X) = g \circ X$. If $X: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ is a random variable measurable-$F$ and if $p_{X}$ is the probability measure induced by $X$, then a fundamental theorem in measure theory (see, say the chapter on probability in Folland's real analysis) shows that 
$$
\int_{\Omega} g\circ X dP = \int_{\mathbb{R}} g(x) dp_{X}(x).
$$ 
If $p_{X}$ is absolutely continuous with respect to the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$, then by the Radon-Nykodym theorem the probability density $f_{X}$ of $X$ exists, and a basic property of Lebesgue-Stieltjes integration asserts that
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}} g(x)dp_{X}(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} g(x)f(x) dx.
$$

Comment: Oh it is just definition as stated!